# Handling Collision Events for multiple objects with physics

Tags: lua, box2d, collision-detection, coronasdk, physics

so I'm building a game with Corona (in lua) where there are multiple objects that include Physic attributes, and currently trying to store, manipulate them in a way where I can make collision handling easier...
the idea is that no 2 out of the 3 objects collide..
the Objects being
1/ a Ball (of many that can be on the screen)
2/ the Table (that has some Physic attributes)
and 3/ Pockets (Which end up just being some invisible rectangles)

out of 2 weeks of processing the mess I've come to this conclusion

- Ball hits off other Ball
- Ball hits off Table
- Table does NOT hit off Pocket (static body)
- Pocket do NOT hit off Ball (static body)
- Ball hits off Pocket

a sample of the code structure
  create the 100 Balls

```
balls = {}
local i = 1
function createBalls ()
        for i = 1,100,1 do -- create the 100 and hide them?

        ball = display.newImage("ball.png")
        ball.isVisible = false
        ball.id = tostring( "ball " ..i )
        balls[#ball+1] = ball 
        sceneGroup:insert(ball[#ball])
    end
end
```

declare 6 pockets (using the id as the flag for collision handling)

```
local Pocket1 = display.newRect( screenWidth * .28, screenHeight * .5, 15, 18) --Left Pocket 60pts
physics.addBody( Pocket1, "kinematic", {isSensor = true})
Pocket1:addEventListener( "collision", Pocket1 ) Pocket1.isVisible = true Pocket1.alpha = 0.5
Pocket1.id ="Left Pocket 60pts"

local Pocket2 = display.newRect( screenWidth * .3945, screenHeight * .556, 15, 18) -- Left Pocket 30pts
physics.addBody( Pocket2, "kinematic", {isSensor = true} )
Pocket2:addEventListener( "collision", Pocket2 ) Pocket2.isVisible = false
Pocket2.id ="Left Pocket 30pts"

local Pocket3 = display.newRect( screenWidth * .512, screenHeight * .490, 15, 18) -- Center Pocket 10 pts
physics.addBody( Pocket3, "kinematic", {isSensor = true} )
Pocket3:addEventListener( "collision", Pocket3 ) Pocket3.isVisible = false
Pocket3.id ="Center Pocket 10pts"

local Pocket4 = display.newRect( screenWidth * .613, screenHeight * .556, 15, 18) -- Right Pocket 30 pts
physics.addBody( Pocket4, "kinematic", {isSensor = true} )
Pocket4:addEventListener( "collision", Pocket4 ) Pocket4.isVisible = false
Pocket4.id ="Right Pocket 30pts"

local Pocket5 = display.newRect( screenWidth * .736, screenHeight * .5, 15, 18) -- Far Right Pocket 60pts
physics.addBody( Pocket5, "kinematic", {isSensor = true} )
Pocket5:addEventListener( "collision", Pocket5 ) Pocket5.isVisible = false
Pocket5.id ="Right Pocket 60pts"

local Pocket6 = display.newRect( screenWidth * .512, screenHeight * .638, 50, 10) -- Kill-z Pocketphysics.addBody( Pocket6, "kinematic", {isSensor = true} )
Pocket6:addEventListener( "collision", Pocket6 ) Pocket6.isVisible = false
Pocket6.id ="Kill Pocket"
```

My problem, collision detection only works on the last ball that was loaded,

(in case anyone asks for the loader function)

```
--handle loader
function shootBall()
    createBalls() --obviously this will now spawn 100 balls

    if ballLoaded == true then 
    r1 = -687.5 r2 = -668
    r3 = 595 r4 = 645
    ball[k].x = screenWidth * .378 ball[k].y = screenHeight * .638
    ball[k]:scale(0.16,0.16)
    ball[k].isVisible = true
    physics.addBody( ball[k], "dynamic", {radius = 5.5, density=15.0, friction=0.8, bounce=0.0 } )
    ball[k]:setLinearVelocity( math.random(r1,r2), math.random(r3,r4))
    --and here it will have done nothing productive other than fill the screen with balls

    end
```

**a Rollback Edit** this was originally what would be called but as you can see isn't organised well at all, given the more recent code is a mess..

```
local i = 1
local balls  = {}

local function spawnBall()

    if i > 0 or  i < 100 then
     balls[i] = display.newImage("ball.png")
     balls[i].id = "ball "..i
     balls[i].x = screenWidth * .378
     balls[i].y = screenHeight * .638
     balls[i]:scale(0.16,0.16)
     balls[i].isVisible = true

     physics.addBody( balls[i], "dynamic", {radius = 5.5, density=15.0, friction=0.8, bounce=0.0 } )
     balls[i]:setLinearVelocity(math.random(-687.5,-668), math.random(595,645))
     sceneGroup:insert(balls[i])
     print(balls[i].id.. " shot")
    i = i + 1

    end

end`
```

Comment: There are some strange (and smelling) things in your code. The createBall function is definetely wrong. Are you sure you know what you are doing here? You create a ball table every loop, store some things there, then store a reference to this table in the table **itself**, but at the beginning (`#ball + 1` will evaluate to 1 for a `k` bigger than 1).

In your loader function, what is k? If it is a global variable, don't do this. Trust me, you don't want to do this this way.

Furthermore, you should be careful with indentation, it also helps spotting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my solution, it's pretty comprehensive I can thank Danny from Corona Labs with most of the solution, passing parameters through a function was on the list but not particularly a priority, but Thanks for most of the work.

```
--on "Press" event
--Function to spawn an object
local function spawn(params)
    local ball = display.newImage(params.image)
    --Set the objects table to a table passed in by parameters
    ball.Table = params.Table
    --Automatically set the table index to be inserted into the next available table index
    ball.index = #ball.Table + 1
    --Give the object a custom name
    ball.id = "ball : " .. ball.index
    --If the object should have a body create it, else dont.
        if params.hasBody then
            --Allow physics parameters to be passed by parameters:
            ball.x = params.x or contentCenterX
            ball.y = params.y or contentCenterY
            ball.isVisible = params.isVisible or false
            ball.radius = params.radius or nil
            ball.density = params.density or 0
            ball.friction = params.friction or 0
            ball.bounce = params.bounce or 0
            ball.isSensor = params.isSensor or false
            ball.bodyType = params.bodyType or "dynamic"
            physics.addBody(ball, ball.bodyType, {radius = ball.radius, density = ball.density, friction = ball.friction, bounce = ball.bounce, isSensor = ball.isSensor})
            ball:setLinearVelocity(params.xVelocity or 0, params.yVelocity or 0)
            ball:scale(params.xScale or 1,params.yScale or 1)

        end
    --The objects group
    ball.group = params.group or nil
    --If the function call has a parameter named group then insert it into the specified group
    ball.group:insert(ball)
    --Insert the object into the table at the specified index
    ball.Table[ball.index] = ball       
    return ball
end
local displayGroup = display.newGroup()
--Create a table to hold balls
local ballTable = {}

--Create spawns
local function  ballSpawn()
    for i=1 ,1,1 do
        local spawns = spawn(

            {
            image = "ball.png",
            Table = ballTable,
            hasBody = true,
            x = screenWidth * .378,
            y = screenHeight * .638,
            isVisible = true,
            bodyType = "dynamic", radius = 5.5, density= 15.0, friction= 0.8, bounce = 0.0,
            xVelocity = math.random(-687.5,-678),
            yVelocity = math.random(595,645),
            xScale = 0.16, yScale = 0.16,
            group = sceneGroup,
            }
            )   
    end
end
```

This is the more atypical part of the code where I wanted to do a key by key test when ever a ball whether it was 3 or 5 or 25, if i=5 and ball: 3 collided with a test collision pocket I wanted to make sure that all collisions printed.

```
local function onPocketsCollision ( event)
local self = event.object2.id
local other = event.object1.id

    if event.phase == "began"  then

        for i = 1, #ballTable,1 do
            if (self == ballTable[i].id and other == Pocket1.id) then
                print(self .. " hit for " .. Pocket1.id)
                ballTable[i]:removeSelf()
                score.add(1)
            end
            if (self == ballTable[i].id and other == Pocket2.id) then
                print(self .. " hit for " .. Pocket2.id)
                ballTable[i]:removeSelf()
                score.add(1)
            end
            if (self == ballTable[i].id and other == Pocket3.id) then
                print(self .. " hit for " .. Pocket3.id)
                ballTable[i]:removeSelf()
                score.add(1)
            end
            if (self == ballTable[i].id and other == Pocket4.id) then
                print(self .. " hit for " .. Pocket4.id)
                ballTable[i]:removeSelf()
                score.add(1)
            end
            if (self == ballTable[i].id and other == Pocket5.id) then
                print(self .. " hit for " .. Pocket5.id)
                ballTable[i]:removeSelf()
                score.add(1)
            end
            if (self == ballTable[i].id and other == Pocket6.id) then
                print(self .. " hit " .. Pocket6.id)
                ballTable[i]:removeSelf()
                score.add(-1)
            end
        end
    end
end


Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onPocketsCollision )
```

fantastically enough, it works great, it was just a case of reducing it down so it didn't look like crap... I'll be sure to take a little care in future when it comes to sharing code, must of been a poop line-by-line to read...

Answer (score 0):

```
function createBalls ()
        for k = 1,100,1 do
        ball = {} -- we do this every loop cycle!!!
        ball[k] = display.newImage("ball.png")
        ball[k].isVisible = false
        ball[k].id = tostring( "ball " ..i )
        ball[#ball+1] = ball[k]
        sceneGroup:insert(ball[#ball])
    end
end
```

Here you re-define the global variable ball 100 times.

As you re-create ball every cycle #ball will always be 1.
So you create a table, add various values to it at index k and 2, then recreate it again... So your global table ball is completely f***ed up.

In `shootBall()` you use index `k` which is not defined in the provided code...

Go through your code line by line and think about it. Use pen an paper and draw a table...

Please read something about the use of local variables in Lua!!!!

Comment: I've posted a rolled back answer to my initial problem.... anyone would understand the reason for k... keys.... v value.... s... search, this enables the end user to release as many balls as they like, it will be restricted at some point, the tip was definitely insightful though :)

Comment: @NealBarry if you want to spawn a number of balls write a function like spawnBalls(numBalls) instead of using global variables to set the number of balls. you want to keep the number of global variables as small as possible. check your edited code for typos. you still have errors in your for loop.

Comment: that's actually helped give me more of an idea of approach, I'm possibly on my forth week working with lua, and even having this much has me astonished, personally can't wait to start calling C functions just to see what happens....